# What literally was the mark of Cain?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, historical-figures, genesis-bereishith

> וַיֹּ֧אמֶר ל֣וֹ יְהוָ֗ה לָכֵן֙ כָּל־הֹרֵ֣ג קַ֔יִן שִׁבְעָתַ֖יִם יֻקָּ֑ם וַיָּ֨שֶׂם יְהוָ֤ה לְקַ֙יִן֙ א֔וֹת לְבִלְתִּ֥י הַכּוֹת־אֹת֖וֹ כָּל־מֹצְאֽוֹ׃
>
> (Genesis 4:15)

What literally was the mark of Cain? Was it a physical blemish, scar tattoo of some kind? Or was it possibly nothing physical at all but some sort of "sign" to warn others not to kill him? What does midrash have to say?

Comment: Are you only looking for Midrashic answers?

Comment: @Alex. Any answers are welcome. The text is obscure so midrash seemed the logical first place to search for answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a sampling of the interpretations offered by the commentators (all taken from commentaries to the verse in question):

- **Rashi**

  God inscribed (part of) His name on Cain's forehead:

  > חקק לו אות משמו במצחו
- **Ibn Ezra**

  - God gave Cain a horn:

  > ויש אומרים כי האות קרן

  - God gave Cain courage and removed his fear:

  > ואחרים אמרו שנתן חוזק בלבו והסיר פחדו ממנו

  - God made a sign for Cain that would cause him to trust God, but it is not identified in the text:

  > והנכון בעיני שהשם עשה לו אות עד שהאמין והכתוב לא גלה האות
- **Bechor Shor**

  God made a sign in heaven or earth until Cain believed that he wouldn't be killed:

  > או בשמים או בארץ עד שהבטיחו שלא יהרג
- **French Scholars**

  God restored the fear to animals:

  > החזיר לו מורא על החיות
- **Radak**

  God gave courage to Cain so he wouldn't fear that anyone would strike him, and He made the animals and other people afraid to attack Cain:

  > שם לו אות בלבו כלומר חזק לבבו שלא יפחד שיכה אותו כל מוצאו ושם מוראו בלב החיות ובני אדם הבאים אחריו שלא יכוהו ועוד נכתוב הדרש שדרשו בזה
- **R. Isaiah of Trani**

  God gave Cain a י from His name so that no one would attack him:

  > וישם י"י לקין אות משמו של הקב"ה שאמו קראתו קין על שם קניתי והי"ל לקרות לו שם ק"ן בלא יוד שם לו הקב"ה משמו אות לבלתי הכות אותו כל מוצאו
- **R. Hezekiah Ben Manoah**

  God gave Cain a sign so that Cain would believe him, but the text does not specify what the sign was:

  > נתן לו אות והאמין בו אך הכתוב לא גילהו
- **Ramban**

  God gave Cain a sign that could accompany him everywhere, showing him where to go so that he would know that no harm would befall him in a given place:

  > ולא אמר ויתן לו השם אות או ויעש יורה ששם לו האות קבוע שיהיה עמו תמיד אולי כשהיה נוסע ממקום למקום היה לו אות מאת השם מורה לו הדרך אשר ילך בה ובזה ידע שלא יקראנו אסון בדרך ההוא
- **Tur**

  God gave Cain a sign that could accompany him everywhere, showing him where to go so that he would know that no harm would befall him in a given place:

  > ולא אמר ויתן לו השם אות ששם לו אות קבוע שיהיה עמו תמיד ואולי כשהיה נוסע ממקום למקום לא היה לו מאת השם מורה הדרך אשר ילך בה ובזה ידע אשר יקראנו אסון בדרך ההוא
- **Ibn Kaspi**

  The text doesn't say what the sign was:

  > לא כתב זה האות בפירוש גמור ולא פירש זה ישעיה באמרו ושמתי בהם אות  אמנם רב ליחידים פירוש גדול בזה לא לאיש כמוני
- **Ralbag**

  What the sign was is disputed by the Sages, but whatever it was it convinced Cain to trust God:

  > וזה האות לא פורש ונחלקו בו רבותינו ז"ל בבראשית רבה והנה היה זה האות באופן שהאמין בו קין איך שהיה ענינו
- **R. Samuel David Luzzato**

  The sign was either God's statement itself which led Cain to believe that no one would kill him, or there was an actual sign but it is not identified in the text:

  > אולי הכוונה ע"י המאמר הזה והשבועה הזאת נתן לו אות והבטיחו שלא יכה אותו כל מוצאו ואולי ג"כ הכוונה אות ממש ולא פירש במה היה האות

Comment: Thank you Alex. That is an amazing response.

Comment: @Ephraim77 You're Welcome.

Comment: Note that a lot of these answers are just quoting the Midrash above.

Comment: @ezra Some of them loosely reference it. I left out some of the parts that more explicitly just quote the Midrash.

Comment: @Ephraim77 mark it as the correct answer and Alex will be able to get +10 points.

Answer (score 19):

Midrash, Bereishit Rabbah 22:12

> וַיָּשֶׂם ה' לְקַיִן אוֹת, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה וְרַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אָמַר הִזְרִיחַ לוֹ גַּלְגַּל חַמָּה, אָמַר רַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה לְאוֹתוֹ רָשָׁע הָיָה מַזְרִיחַ לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא גַּלְגַּל חַמָּה, אֶלָּא מְלַמֵּד שֶׁהִזְרִיחַ לוֹ הַצָּרַעַת, הֵיךְ מָה דְאַתְּ אָמַר וְהָיָה אִם לֹא יַאֲמִינוּ לָךְ וְלֹא יִשְׁמְעוּ לְקֹל הָאֹת וגו'. רַב אָמַר כֶּלֶב מָסַר לוֹ. אַבָּא יוֹסֵי בֶּן קֵסָרִי אָמַר קֶרֶן הִצְמִיחַ לוֹ. רַב אָמַר עֲשָׂאוֹ אוֹת לְרוֹצְחָנִים. רַבִּי חָנִין אָמַר עֲשָאוֹ אוֹת לְבַעֲלֵי תְּשׁוּבָה. רַבִּי לֵוִי בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן לָקִישׁ אָמַר תְּלָאוֹ בְּרִפְיוֹן וּבָא מַבּוּל וּשְׁטָפוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וַיִּמַח אֶת כָּל הַיְקוּם אֲשֶׁר עַל פְּנֵי הָאֲדָמָה, כְּמָה דְאַתְּ אָמַר וַיָּקָם קַיִן וגו'.
>
> "And Hashem set a sign for Kayin." (Bereishit 4:15) Rabbi Yehudah said: He caused the sphere of the sun to shine on his account. Rabbi Nechemiah said: *HaKadosh Baruch Hu* caused the sphere of the sun to sign on account of the wicked!? Rather, He caused *tzara'at* to break out on him, as you read, "And it shall be, if they will not believe you, or listen to the voice of the first sign, etc." (Shemot 4:8) Rav said: He gave him a dog. Abba Yosei ben Keisari said: He caused a horn to grow from him. Rav said: He made him a sign (example) to murderers. Rabbi Chanin said: He made him a sign (example) to those who do *teshuvah* (repentence). Rabbi Levi said in the name of Rabbi Shimon ben Lakish: He postponed his judgment until the Flood swept him away, as it is said, "And he wiped out everything on the surface of the earth, etc." (Bereishit 7:23)

On a side note, Rashi says Hashem engraved a letter of His Name on Kayin's forehead. Ramban quotes Rav above and says Hashem gave Kayin a guide dog. Most of the commentators are quiet about this or admit the Torah gives us little information about what this sign was.

Answer (score 8):

No answer is complete without the Kabbalistic interpretation Tikkunei Zohar 118,2:

> הָכָא תָב בִּתְיוּבְתָּא וְאִתְחַרַט, בְּגִין דָּא וַיָּשֶׂם יהו"ה לְקַיִן אוֹת (שם, טו), הָכָא רָמַז אוֹת בְּרִית מִילָה דְקַבִּיל יִתְרוֹ, דְאִתְּמַר בֵּיהּ (שופטים א, טז) וּבְנֵי קֵנִי חוֹתֵן מֹשֶׁה שֶׁנִּפְרַד מִקַּיִן, (צ"ל: (שם ד, יא) וחבר הקני נפרד מקין), וּבְיִתְרוֹ אִתְתַּקַּן קַיִן מֵחוֹבֵיהּ,
>   Kayin regretted killing Hevel with a full heart and Hashem gave him a sign that his Teshuva was Accepted this was the Bris  Mila which is call an אוֹת (Bereishis 17.13) that Yisro who is called קֵנִי (same letter as קַיִן) fulfilled upon himself when converting to Judaism. Yisro who was a *Gilgul* of Kayin, fully atoned the sin of Kayin.

It is not for nothing that Kayin is brought as an example to emulate when we suplicate to Hashem to atone for our sins on Tzom Gedalia during Selichos in the Pizmon "הורת דרך תשובה לבת השובבה"

> טָעָה גִזְעוֹ דְּמֵי־אָחִיו בְּשָׁפְכוֹ. יִסַּרְתּוֹ בְּנָע וָנָד, לֶכֶת כֹּה וָכֹה. **כָּעֵת שָׁב־אֵלֶיךָ, וְעָזַב רֹעַ דַּרְכּוֹ**. לְשִׁבְעָתַיִם הֶאֱרַכְתּוֹ, כָּל־מוֹצְאוֹ בְּלִי־לְהַכּוֹ. הֲשִׁיבֵנוּ ה' אֵלֶיךָ, וְנָשׁוּבָה: